# Azure Analytics HTTP Api call using Node Js getting ECONNRESET message

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-log-analytics

Using below code snippet to make a call to Azure HTTP and i am getting an exception as "Error: read ECONNRESET"

```
var request = require('request');
var workspaceId = '***********************************';
var sharedKey = '*****************************************************';
var apiVersion = '2016-04-01';
var processingDate = new Date().toUTCString();
var body = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
var contentLength = Buffer.byteLength(body, 'utf8');
var stringToSign = 'POST\n' + contentLength + '\napplication/json\nx-ms-date:' + processingDate + 
'\n/api/logs';
var signature = crypto.createHmac('sha256', new Buffer(sharedKey, 'base64')).update(stringToSign, 
'utf-8').digest('base64');
var authorization = 'SharedKey ' + workspaceId + ':' + signature;
var headers = {
"Accept": "application/json",
"Authorization": authorization,
"Log-Type": 'WebMonitorTest',
"x-ms-date": processingDate
};

var url = 'https://' + workspaceId + '.ods.opinsights.azure.com/api/logs?api-version=' + apiVersion;
request.post({url: url, headers: headers, body: body}, function (error, response, body)
```

Comment: have you seen this issuecoments : see this if it can help you: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/issues/1255#issue-37639562

Comment: Kindly do share your *error logs*.

Comment: @devUser Do you have any other concerns? If you have no other concerns, could you please accept the answer? It can help more people who have the issue.

Answer (score 1):

According to my test, if you want to call HTTP Data Collector API, please refer to the following steps. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/data-collector-api).

1. [Get Share Key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/workspaces/getsharedkeys)

```
az login
az account set --subscription <the subscription you use>
az monitor log-analytics workspace get-shared-keys --resource-group <> --workspace-name <>
```

2. Code

```
var crypto = require("crypto")
var request = require('request');
async function main() {
    var json = {
        "StringValue": "MyString1",
        "NumberValue": 42,
        "BooleanValue": true,
        "DateValue": "2019-09-12T20:00:00.625Z",
        "GUIDValue": "9909ED01-A74C-4874-8ABF-D2678E3AE23D"
    }
    var json1={
        "StringValue": "MyString2",
        "NumberValue": 43,
        "BooleanValue": false,
        "DateValue": "2019-09-12T20:00:00.625Z",
        "GUIDValue": "8809ED01-A74C-4874-8ABF-D2678E3AE23D"
    }
    var o =[]
    o.push(json)
    o.push(json1)
    var body = JSON.stringify(o)
    var contentLength =Buffer.byteLength(body,'utf8');
    var key = ''
    var workspaceId = '';
    var apiVersion = '2016-04-01';
    var GMTTime = new Date().toUTCString()

    var StringToSign = 'POST' + '\n'
         + contentLength+'\n'
        + 'application/json' + '\n'
        +'x-ms-date:'+ GMTTime + '\n'
        + '/api/logs'  
    var Sig = crypto.createHmac('sha256', Buffer.from(key, 'base64')).update(StringToSign, 'utf-8').digest('base64');

    var authorization = 'SharedKey ' + workspaceId + ':' + Sig;
    var headers = {
        "Content-Type":"application/json",
        "Authorization": authorization,
        "Log-Type": 'demoexample',
        "x-ms-date": GMTTime,
        "time-generated-field" : new Date().toISOString
    };
    var url = 'https://' + workspaceId + '.ods.opinsights.azure.com/api/logs?api-version=' + apiVersion;
    request.post({ url: url, headers: headers, body: body }, function (error, response){

          if (error){
              console.log(error)

          }else{

            console.log(response.statusCode + "   " + response.statusMessage)
          }

    })
}

main()
```

[image]